# Image Detection & Classification - general approach?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, object-detection, image-recognition, faster-rcnn

I'm trying to build a detection + classification model that will recognize an object in an image and classify it. Every image will contain at most 1 object among my 10 classes (i.e. same image cannot contains 2 classes). An image can, however, contain none of my classes/objects. I'm struggling with the general approach to this problem, especially due to the nature of my problem; my objects have different sizes. This is what I have tried:

1. Trained a classifier with images that only contains my objects/classes, i.e. every image is the object itself with background pre-removed. Now, since the objects/images have different shapes (aspect ratios) I had to reshape the images to the same size (destroying the aspect ratios). This would work just fine if my purpose was to only build a classifier, but since I also need to detect the objects, this didn't work so good.
2. The second approach was similar to (1), except that I didn't reshape the objects naively, but kept the aspect ratios by padding the image with 0 (black). This completely destroyed my classifiers ability to perform well (accuracy < 5%).
3. Mask RCNN - I followed [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/object-detection-using-mask-r-cnn-on-a-custom-dataset-4f79ab692f6d) blogpost to try build a detector + classifier in the same model. The approach took forever and I wasn't sure it was the right approach. I even used external tools (RectLabel) to generate annotated image files containing information about the bounding boxes.

Question:
How should I approach this problem, on a general level:

- Should I build 2 separate models? (One for detection/localization and one for classification?)
- Should I be annotating my images using annotations file as in approach (3)?
- Do I have to reshape my images at any stage?

Thanks,

PS. In all of my approaches, I augmented the images to generate ~500-1000 images per class.

Comment: Have you tried the implementation in https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN? It looks pretty good and there is also an example with custom dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your questions:

- No, you don't have to build two separate models. What you are describing is called **Object detection**, which is classification along with localization. There are many models which do this: [Mask_RCNN](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN), [Yolo](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet), [Detectron](https://github.com/facebookresearch/Detectron), [SSD](https://github.com/balancap/SSD-Tensorflow), etc..
- Yes, you do need to annotate your images for training a model for your custom classes. Each of the models mentioned above has needs a different way of annotation.
- No, you don't need to do any image resizing. Most of the time it is done when the model loads the data for training or inference.

You are on the right track with trying *MaskRCNN*.

Other than MaskRCNN, you could also try [Yolo](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet). There is also an accompanying easy-to-use annotating tool [Yolo-Mark](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/Yolo_mark).

Comment: Thx. I'm reading these blogposts:
https://machinelearningmastery.com/object-recognition-with-deep-learning/
https://towardsdatascience.com/a-hitchhikers-guide-to-object-detection-and-instance-segmentation-ac0146fe8e11

Both of these are referring to "object detection" as a scheme to detect multiple objects in the same image, whereas I would only be interested in a single class.

Are there faster algorithms than MaskRCNN that could accomplish this? Or is it still frameworks like YOLOv3, etc. that I should stick to ?

Comment: You can train any of the object detector mentioned above with just one class. I don't know what you mean by algorithms for MaskRCNN and frameworks for Yolov3 in your comment above. They are both DL models for me. For a beginner, I'd say, try any one of the github repos linked above and see which is easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

If you go through this tutorial, you would understand what you care about.
[How to train your own Object Detector with TensorFlow’s Object Detector API](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-train-your-own-object-detector-with-tensorflows-object-detector-api-bec72ecfe1d9)

The SSD model is small so that it would not take so much time for training.
[There are some object detection models.](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md)

On RectLabel, you can save bounding boxes in the PASCAL VOC format.
You can export TFRecord for Tensorflow.
https://rectlabel.com/help#tf_record